# Delphi call TDBGrid.Datasource.Dataset.Refresh from a background thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firedac

I want to handle refreshing this data source in a separate thread. Currently it is being updated in the main thread.

`DBGrid` is a `TDBGrid` and is bound to a dataset and a `TFDQuery`. In the contructor for the the form i set the DB connection and call `Open` on the query. After that i continually call the `updateview` on a timer from the main thread.

So my question is, can i simply put the call `DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;` into a separate thread or do i need to manually call the query Close and Open function in a separate thread and in a call to Syncronize set the dataset on the `DBGrid.DataSource` ?

```
procedure TMySimpleView.UpdateView;
begin

  try
    DBGrid.DataSource.DataSet.Refresh;
  except
    ON E: Exception DO begin
      //Handle Exception
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You have to invoke it by `Synchronize`.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you question. I Basicly cant figure out if calling the DBGrid.DataSource.Dataset.Refresh is ok to to i a thread, or if it needs to be called in the main thread since it updates the TDBGrid which is a VCL component.

Comment: No, you can't call it from a thread unless you use synchronize which is fact will make it executed from the main thread. Using a thread for that purpose in completely useless. The good question is why do you think it would be better if executed from a worker thread?

Comment: The reason would be to have the query to the database handled in a background thread, as the data at some point might be pretty big.

Comment: Then the thread has to create its own connection to the database, and all the components using that database from the thread must use that connection. Also, a TDBGrid is part of the VCL, which is not thread safe, so you can't access the TDBGrid from anywhere except the main thread at all - you have to synchronize access through the main thread.

Comment: Does the data change frequently? And when it changes, is it only added/removed records or anything can happen with the data? When data change, what is the volume of changes compare to the total data volume? My idea is to optimize the process of updating the screen with changed data.